# What should be stored in source control for an Asp.Net Core MVC application?

Tags: version-control, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

With the new Asp.net Core MVC projects such as:

[image]

There are a lot of unfamiliar folders there, like `bower_components`, `wwwroot`, `Dependencies`, etc..

**What should be stored in source control?**

Comment: You didn't mention which source control you are using, but there is a [.gitignore for Visual Studio](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) that is being kept up to date with the standard set of things to ignore (even in VS 2015/.NET Core/DNX). You could always adapt it for whatever source control you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with

[image]

(With green being yes, red being no)

The only unlisted exception was the `.xproj` (and for TFS the `.xproj.vspscc`).

I deleted the folder from my local workspace (after backing up to somewhere else) and restored from source control and everything seems to behave as it should, once all the packages restored themselves.

This assumes that the `gulpfile.js` is configured to move the needed `css`, `js`, `font` components into `wwwroot`.

Also since I wrote this, there is a `launchSettings.json` within the `properties` folder that I've source controlled (Not sure why it's only just generated).

---

My `.tfsignore` file is currently:

```
project\wwwroot
!project\wwwroot\web.config
project\node_modules
project\bower_components
```

(which seems to be OK so far, but would potentially change if other static resources such as JS, CSS and Images were added in.)

Comment: You shouldn't ignore the wwwroot, because it also contains your custom images, CSS and JavaScript files ;)

Comment: @JuergenGutsch I thought the idea was to use the `gulpfile.js` to move any custom CSS / JS into an appropiate bundle?

Comment: yes, but gulp (even grunt) this is completely independent from the wwwroot. gulp checks for the files in the wwwroot to uglify and to bundle the files, but the original files are also located in the wwwroot folder.

You need to commit this files to the source control to share your work in this files with any other developer in your team ;)

Comment: @JuergenGutsch Interesting. I was going to aim to have `wwwroot` slimmed down to only have what was released within it, granted I would need to amend the ignores to not have images in there.

Comment: It could be possible to have these files (images, scripts and css) outside the wwwroot, but you need to ensure that the files are in there at the end. This will not be done automatically. Means "wwwroot" is not the new "bin", but the root directory of your web application.

Comment: It's a bit Off Topic (but very interesting) but my idea was to use some sort of pre-processor SASS for CSS, maybe TypeScript for Js, and drop the result into wwwroot rather than having the files in there. I have updated the answer to have more generic image / js detail in there.

Comment: Two options: 1. use gulp to 'compile' into CSS and JavaScripts, there are add-ins available (compile on build). 2. use vswebessentials.com to edit LESS, SASS, TS and compile on save.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is a project setting, or that you directly change you should store. Anything that is directly downloaded (references, bower/node) or is directly based on those (lib folder getting copied by gulp) should be ignored.

So, in your case, ignore bower, node, and project\wwwroot\lib.  You want the wwwroot folder if you have custom css or js.