# ASP.NET core 2.0 MVC project. Should wwwroot be excluded from source control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I just created a ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC project. By default, it appears that all the files under "wwwroot/*" folders are automatically added to source control and are ready to be checked in. However, I am wondering if checking wwwwroot files is necessary.

Here are the files under wwwroot:

```
wwwroot/css -> site.css, site.min.css
wwwroot/images -> banner1.svg, banner2.svg etc
wwwroot/js - site.js, site.min.js
wwwroot/lib - folders boostrap, jquery, jquery-validation, etc.
```

I found one post that seemed relevant: [What should be stored in source control for an Asp.Net Core MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411417/what-should-be-stored-in-source-control-for-an-asp-net-core-mvc-application)

The post says that wwwroot can be ignored except wwwroot/web.config. However, this post may have been more relevant for older ASP.NET versions as web.config is no longer used. It has been replaced with appsettings.json.

It appears that wwwroot folder contains all the packages defined in bower.json. I am thinking bower files can be restored by developers as needed.

Can someone please confirm if it is okay to ignore wwwroot from source control? Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should be stored in source control for an Asp.Net Core MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411417/what-should-be-stored-in-source-control-for-an-asp-net-core-mvc-application)

Comment: The .gitignore file linked in the duplicate was last edited 17 days ago. The second answer, _"Anything that is a project setting, or that you directly change you should store. Anything that is directly downloaded (references, bower/node) or is directly based on those (lib folder getting copied by gulp) should be ignored"_, always applies.