# ASP.NET Core 2.1 - Should wwwroot be excluded from source control?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have asked a similar question earlier: [ASP.NET core 2.0 MVC project. Should wwwroot be excluded from source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924300/asp-net-core-2-0-mvc-project-should-wwwroot-be-excluded-from-source-control) and was pointed to a `.gitignore` file at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore that is continuously being updated.

When you create a new ASP.NET Core project (Razor in my case), a bunch of files are automatically generated under `wwwroot` folder. According to the comment in the `.gitignore` file, as `wwwroot` folder contains static files, it can safely be excluded from source control check-ins. However, I see a bunch of `bower.json` files under this folder:

```
./wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/.bower.json
./wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/.bower.json
./wwwroot/lib/jquery/.bower.json
./wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation/.bower.json
```

My question is, even if I exclude `wwwroot` folder, shouldn't we need to check in these bower files to re-build `wwwroot` folder on a new machine?

Answer (score 5):

First, `wwwroot` should *not* be ignored. That's where your project's static resources should go, and you'll need those committed to source control to track changes to CSS, JS, etc. However, the `wwwroot/lib` folder *should* be ignored, as these are external libraries that can be restored; you only want to commit *your* code, not other people's.

The `.bower.json` files are pulled in from restoring those bower packages, so that's not something you need to have in your source control. It's similar to npm's `package.json` files, which are actually part of the package itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help Chris. What is the command to restore wwwroot/lib? I don't see any configuration file that lists the bower packages to be restored (bootstrap, jquery, etc.)

Comment: It used to happen automatically, or you could utilize a GUI like for NuGet. However, Bower has been deprecated, and I'm honestly, not even sure of the integration is still in Visual Studio at this point. Going forward, you should switch to LibMan or npm.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the comment. It says

> Uncomment if you have tasks that create the project's static files in
>   wwwroot

It should be ignored only if everything in your wwwroot is autogenerated, via bower, npm or other (it's the same for NuGet and `packages` folder). But, since it's used also for user-managed static files (js libs, images, ...), it can't be ignored by default.